# Seeking a passage of Aristotle on contradiciton

Tags: history-of-philosophy, aristotle, argumentation

Aristotle says only someone who has been well brought up can be "a competent student of the Right and Just, and in short of the topics of Politics in general" (Nic. Eth. 1095b).  And I believe he somewhere says, similarly, that you cannot argue rationally with (or, perhaps cannot teach logic to) someone who is willing to maintain a contradiction.  But I do not find that passage.

Is such a claim about contradiction found in what we have of Aristotle?

Comment: See the extended Aristotle quote in [_Four Ages of Understanding_ pp. 125](https://books.google.com/books?id=zAsjkHJ8aP8C&pg=125)ff., § "How to Deal with Contradictions?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental discussion of [non-contradiction by Aristotle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-noncontradiction/) is in *Met*, Book IV:

> [[1005b](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0052%3Abook%3D4%3Asection%3D1005b)] it is impossible for the same
>   man at the same time to believe the same thing to be and not to be; for if a man
>   were mistaken in this point he would have contrary opinions at the same time.
>
> For it is impossible that there should be demonstration of absolutely everything; there would be an infinite regress, so that there would still be no demonstration. But if there are things of which one should not demand demonstration, these persons cannot say what principle they regard as more indemonstrable than the present one.
>
> [[1006a](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0052%3Abook%3D4%3Asection%3D1006a)] We can, however, demonstrate negatively even that this view is impossible, if our opponent will only say something; and if he says nothing, it is absurd to
>   attempt to reason with one who will not reason about anything, in so far as he
>   refuses to reason. [...] The starting-point for all such arguments is not the
>   demand that our opponent shall say that something either is or is not (for this one might perhaps take to be assuming what is at issue), but that he shall say something which is significant both for himself and for another; for this is necessary, if he really is to say anything. For, if he means nothing, such a man will not be capable of reasoning, either with himself or with another.

See also:

- R.M. Dancy, [Sense and Contradiction: A Study in Aristotle](https://books.google.it/books?id=0rkJCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1975).